Clarity on Java Lambda Syntax
From my understanding, this is a single statement in Java:
while((x % p == 0l) && (x > p)) x /= p;

If that is the case, why is this a syntax error:
final AtomicLong subtotal = new AtomicLong(limit);

final long maxPrimeFactor = primeStream.takeWhile(p -> p * p <= limit)
                                       .filter(p -> subtotal.get() % p == 0)
                                       .peek(p -> while((subtotal.get() % p == 0) && (subtotal.get() > p)) subtotal.set(subtotal.get() / p)) // Syntax error here.
                                       .dropWhile(p -> p != subtotal.get())
                                       .findFirst()
                                       .getAsLong();

And this is not a syntax error.
final AtomicLong subtotal = new AtomicLong(limit);

final long maxPrimeFactor = primeStream.takeWhile(p -> p * p <= limit)
                                       .filter(p -> subtotal.get() % p == 0)
                                       .peek(p -> { while((subtotal.get() % p == 0) && (subtotal.get() > p)) subtotal.set(subtotal.get() / p)); } // No syntax error here.
                                       .dropWhile(p -> p != subtotal.get())
                                       .findFirst()
                                       .getAsLong();


Show us full text of the error.

A while loop with body is not a single statement.

@ElliottFrisch technically it is single statement. Some statement can contain another statements inside.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se22/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5

Specifically The while Statement

@talex Maybe. It gives the breakdown as WhileStatement: while ( Expression ) Statement which means it is two statements in one as you said, but the Expression could terminate in which case the sub-statement does not execute. Thus, if they are one statement, it is not atomic.

It is called WhileStatement. What else do you need? What definition of statement do you use?


this is a single statement in Java

Yes. Keyword, statement. If you use braceless lambda syntax, the one thing to the right of the arrow must be an expression. That while statement isn't one, so it isn't legal. See JLS §15.27.
Where you may be confused, is this somewhat odd concept in java called 'expression statements'.
Some things in java are both a statement and an expression (or, rather, they are expressions that can be turned into a statement simply by adding a semi-colon). The list is fairly small. The most obvious ones:

method invocations.
constructor invocations (bit odd to ignore what you made, but it's allowed).
operators that mutate. x++ for example. Or x = 5 (which is an expression! int x = 10; int y = x = 15; is legal java, and results in both x and y being '15'. The result of an assignment expression is the value of the thing that is assigned).

Methods that return void are a particularly weird kind of expression statement. Whilst they are expressions, using them in any way other than as a statement is a compiler error due to the void part of it.
Point is, all the expression statements, even void-returning methods, are still considered expressions, and therefore can form the business end of a lambda expression without braces.
while is not a expression statement; it's just a statement. Therefore, cannot appear to the right of that arrow (at least, not without braces).
If you want real weirdness, check out switch. Which isn't quite a statement expression, but can be used as an expression, or as a statement (in recent versions of java, at least).

"Some things in java are both a statement and an expression" that is not true. foo() is expression, foo(); is statement.

There is no such thing as "statement expression". You probably mean "expression statement".

switch expression and switch statement have different syntax,

@talex  Care to elaborate?  I'd like to see an example of each.

@TrippKinetics possible that expressions use case FOO -> instead of case FOO:, but oracle themselves also call the arrow notation as 'switch statements', and you can use them in statement-switches. It feels like talex is on a pedantry mission and they've overreached on that one.

@rzwitserloot fair enough. I assume that switch epression can be used as statement because it is expression statement, but if oracle see it other way, then I'm wrong. And yes, you guessed my mission correctly :)

p->something expect something to be expression, not statement.
p->{something} expect something to be statement or, to be precise, list of statements.
See: 15.27. Lambda Expressions
Specifically 15.27.2. Lambda Body:
LambdaBody:
   Expression
   Block 

Block:
   { [BlockStatements] } 

